# Ionic serve no corre

Tags: ionic

cli packages: (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v6.11.2/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.9.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.9.2
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
Node : v6.11.2
npm  : 3.10.10 
OS   : Linux 4.10
```

Comment: ¿cuál es el error que aparece?

Comment: Error: Missing binding /home/daleney/Ionic/myApp/node_modules/node-sass/vendor/linux-x64-48/binding.node
Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Linux 64-bit with Node.js 6.x

Found bindings for the following environments:
  - Linux 64-bit with Node.js 8.x

This usually happens because your environment has changed since running `npm install`.
Run `npm rebuild node-sass --force` to build the binding for your current environment.

Comment: "npm rebuild node-sass --force" no lo soluciona